# Pull only values from array in JSON output

Tags: jquery, json

I have below output from server AJAX JSON,

```
teams:[{team_id: "1"}, {team_id: "2"}]
```

I want to convert it to in just simple array of values with Jquery in my JS file, like `[1, 2]`. Means just values, no key of team_id.

How can i do this?

thanks,

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to iterate over the array, extract the `team_id` for each item, and assemble a new array from the values. Where exactly are you having problems with this? Can you share with us the code you have now?

Answer (score 1):

```
let newArray = [];
let oldArray = [{team_id: "1"}, {team_id: "2"}]

oldArray.forEach((obj)=>{ newArray.push(obj.team_id) })
```

For immutability you can save it to new array.

Edit: As you noticed from the answers you don't even need jQuery for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` Array method:

```
var teamsNew = teams.map(function(team) {
    return team.team_id;
});
```

You must consider that your ids are being stored as strings. If you want to change it to integer as ids use to be, you can do it with `parseInt()` function.

```
var teamsNew = teams.map(function(team) {
    return parseInt(team.team_id);
});
```

You may want to use arrow function notation.

```
var teamsNew = teams.map(team => parseInt(team.team_id));
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: nice catch with the string and `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Not very difficult. You could try this:

```
let newArray = [];
for (team of teams) { 
newArray.push(team.team_id);
};
```